# No isomorphism between $(\mathbb R,+)$ and $(\mathbb R^*, \times)$

Tags: proof-verification, abstract-algebra

My goal is to disprove the existence of an isomorphism between $(\mathbb R,+)$ and $(\mathbb R^*, \times)$.

I proceeded by contradiction. Suppose $f$ is such a map.

Then $$f(0-0)=f(0)f(-0)=-f(0)^2$$
$$ f(0+0)=f(0)^2$$

$$f(0-0)=f(0+0)=f(0)$$

$$-f(0)^2=f(0)^2$$

thus, $$f(0)=0$$

This contradicts the fact that $f(0) \in \mathbb R^*$

Is this proof right ? It looks overly simple to me and doesn't use the one-to-one property of $f$.

EDIT: the proof is indeed flawed: check answers below.
For those looking for a valid one : let $x=f^{-1}(1)$ and $y=f^{-1}(-1)$. Then $x \neq y$ $$f(2x)=f(x)^2=1^2=(-1)^2=f(2y)$$
Since $f$ is one-to-one, $$2x=2y$$

$$x=y$$

Comment: point no $1$ : you are not supposed to write $f(0-0)=f(0)f(-0)$ if what you really meant is $f(0.(-0))=f(0)f(-0)$.

Point No $2$ : You are using $f(-0)=-f(0)$ which may not be true.. It would be helpful for you if you can try checking it now!

Comment: A very suspicious fact about your argument is that it "proves" that the exponential is zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You used $f(-0)=-f(0)$ but this isn't true. The inverse in the multiplicative group is $x\mapsto \cfrac{1}{x}$. So $f(-0)=\cfrac{1}{f(0)}$

---

To find the "usual" proof, notice that $\exp$ is an isomorphism between $(\Bbb R,+)$ and $(\Bbb R_+^*, \times)$ but here, you have $(\Bbb R^*, \times)$ which is "bigger", approximately twice as "big". So maybe, you could find a property so that in the first group, you have only one element verifying that property and in the second group, you have two.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I provided a valid proof which uses squares.

Answer (score 3):

Other arguments may be:

- If $f : (\mathbb{R},+) \to (\mathbb{R}^*, \times)$ is a morphism, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ $$f(x)=f \left( 2 \frac{x}{2} \right)= f \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^2 \geq 0,$$ hence $\mathrm{Im}(f) \subset \mathbb{R}_+^*$. In particular, $f$ cannot be an isomorphism.
- $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is a ($2$-)divisible group but not $(\mathbb{R}^*, \times)$ (for example, $-1$ has no square root).

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest possible argument (pretty much the same as the one you've ended up at) is as follows: the additive group is torsion-free, but in the multiplicative group, $(-1)^2=1$.

A slight modification of this argument works for *any* field (in fact, any domain): for any field $k$, if characteristic of $k$ is $0$, then $(k,+)$ is torsion-free, but $-1\neq 1$ and $(-1)^2=1$. If chracteristic of $k$ is $p>0$, then $1$ has order $p$ in $(k,+)$, but in the multiplicative group there is no element of order $p$: if $x^p=1$, then $0=x^p-1=(x-1)^p$ so $x=1$.

Comment: Can you quickly define what torsion is?

Comment: An element $g\in G$ is torsion if $g\neq e$ and there is an $n$ such that $g^n=e$ (i.e. it has finite order). A group is torsion-free if it has no torsion elements.